# Concatenating FormattableString

Tags: c#, string

Is it possible to concatenate two FormattableStrings into a new FormattableString and preserve all arguments?

```
int i = 1; string s = "s"; bool b = true;
FormattableString str = $"I:{i}, S:{s}";
FormattableString str2 = $", B:{b}";

var str3 = FormattableStringFactory.Create(str.Format + str2.Format, str.GetArguments().Concat( str2.GetArguments() ) );
```

This fails because the str2.Format produces ", B:{0}" rather than ", B:{2}".

Is there an API that can tokenize the .Format string so that I can manually renumber the indexes?

Comment: I think it's possible but no ready api in .net. May I ask why do you want this?

Comment: To support composing scripts for interop and allow deferred argument replacement.  The only issue I have is I have to compose the entire formattable string in one context, so scenarios where I need to do incremental composition at different layers requires I use string.Format to remap the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your customer formatter class handle recursive FormattedStrings. We can store FormattedStrings inside FormattedStrings. Your custom formatter class can recursively resolve each nested `FormattedString`.

```cs
public class MyCustomFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public object GetFormat(Type formatType) => this;
    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        return arg switch
        {
            FormattableString fs => fs.ToString(this), //Recursive formatting
            decimal i => i.ToString("0.00"), //custom decimal format logic as an example
            //more cases for custom format logic here
            
            _ => arg.ToString()};
    }
}
```

Then you can safely nest formatted strings within formatted strings like so:

```cs
FormattableString str1 = $"Item1: ${3m}";
FormattableString str2 = $"Item2: ${1.2m}";

FormattableString combined = $"{str1}\n{str2}"; //concatenate two formatted strings

//now convert the formatted string into a proper string using our custom formatter
var formatted = combined.ToString(new MyCustomFormatter()); 
Console.WriteLine(formatted);
```

This will print out

```
Item1: $3.00
Item2: $1.20
```